# How to arrange divs in a custom pattern, while having more divs flow regularly after them?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 div blocks that I want to arrange in a pattern.  I tried using float, position, flex CSS directives, but nothing seems to work.  Looking at other answers and trying to set margins, or float, or width doesn't seem to work, my divs just ignore the float commands.  I removed all my tries from the code below as any floats or margins that I use mess up the divs, make them coincide with each other, etc., which would obscure my question.

Using `display: flex` does not help, as it arranges all divs side by side and I need something else.

**Question**

How do I arrange `RIGHT TOP` and `RIGHT BOTTOM` divs to be on the right of `LEFT SIDE` div?

To clarify ... `LEFT SIDE` is the first column, and the `RIGHT` divs are in the 2nd column, and `BOTTOM` div should be below all the previous divs.

```css
#block1 {} #one {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
#two {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#three {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
  <div id="one">LEFT SIDE</div>
  <div id="two">RIGHT TOP</div>
  <div id="three">RIGHT BOTTOM</div>
</div>

<div id="block2">
  BELOW
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap the two right divs in a wrapper and float it to the left of the left div. Then you can clear the bottom div to have it appear below them all.

```css
#block1 {} #one {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
#one, #right-wrapper {
  float: left;
}
#two {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#three {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
  <div id="one">LEFT SIDE</div>
  <div id="right-wrapper">
    <div id="two">RIGHT TOP</div>
    <div id="three">RIGHT BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="block2">
  BELOW
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood right you want this. So simply add a wrapper and float it!

```css
#block1 {
  overflow: auto;  
} 
#one {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
#one{
    float: left;
}
#boxer{
    float: left;
}
#two {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#three {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
  <div id="one">LEFT SIDE</div>
  <div id="boxer">
    <div id="two">RIGHT TOP</div>
    <div id="three">RIGHT BOTTOM</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="block2">
  BELOW
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? I'm not sure where you want LEFT SIDE and BELOW. I clipped LEFT SIDE to the left and to the top. And BELOW to the bottom and center (note the half of the width ofset to the 50%).

```css
#block1 {} #one {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#two {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
#three {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
#block2 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
  <div id="one">LEFT SIDE</div>
  <div id="two">RIGHT TOP</div>
  <div id="three">RIGHT BOTTOM</div>
</div>

<div id="block2">
  BELOW
</div>
```